# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') at StudentDetails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, react-fullstack

## So i'm having a problem where i want to pass the created student application from my server-side to my client-side and whenever I create the new student i want to retrieve his/her info on my StudentDetails.jsx

### this is my Server.js

```
app.post('/application', async (req, res) => {
    let student = new StudentApplicationData({
        email: req.body.email,
        address: req.body.address,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    try {
        student = await student.save()
        res.json({ 
            status: 'ok', 
            student: student
        });

    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'error',
            message: error.message
        });
    }
})

app.get('/students/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const student = await StudentApplicationData.findById(req.params.id)
      res.json(student);
})
```

### this is my Application.jsx

```
    async function sendApplication(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/application', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                address,
                description
            })
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        if (data.status == 'ok') {
            navigateTo(`/students/${data.student._id}`);
        }
    }
```

### this is my App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import StudentDetails from './pages/StudentDetails';


export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/students/:id" element={<StudentDetails />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

## this is my StudentDetails.jsx component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function StudentDetails({ match }) {
    const [student, setStudent] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/api/students/${match.params.id}`)
            .then(response =>   {
                setStudent(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {   
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, [match.params.id]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Student Details</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I know this is very simple but I'm stuck here and cannot go further... Any help would be appreciated!

I tried to debug using `console.log(data.student)` on StudentDetails page and it didn't work out.

Comment: The Error is clearly saying that params are `undefined` in StudentDetails.jsx .

Comment: Yet i've defined it , the params are being passed as a prop from App.jsx

Comment: See your code you haven't pass down the props in App.jsx

Comment: thanks @ShankajaAroshana for your help! i've used this hooks called `useParams()` to match dynamic params from the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you've pass down the props ,like this

```
<Route path="/students/:id" element={<StudentDetails match={match} />} />
```

---

After you've passed the props , to avoid this undefined error you could use
[`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on this line,

> Remember this will only ignore undefined variable, doesn't fix the problem

```
fetch(`/api/students/${match?.params?.id}`)
```

> See the `?` before every key

The optional chaining `(?.)` operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression short circuits and evaluates to `undefined` instead of throwing an error.